# Using QUERY() to sum columns with blanks

Tags: google-sheets

So I have two columns representing quantities. The second column has some blank cells in some of its rows. When I use QUERY on this range and try to use SUM inside the query to SUM the two columns into a single column, wherever the second column is blank, the resulting sum column also displays blank (instead of considering the blank as a zero and hence just displaying the first column's value + 0 = first column's value).

As an example:

Column1, Column2, SumColumn
12, BLANK, BLANK
10,5, 15

The first row should be 12+BLANK=12. How can I do this within QUERY()?

Comment: Please do read [ask] so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @user20777937 if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76460191/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to use QUERY to SUM the 2 columns into a single column and you need that the formula considers a `BLANK` space as `0`. I created a Google Sheet file example that includes 2 columns the second column includes some cells in `BLANK`

[image]

In order for you to obtain the **SumColumn** result considering the `BLANK` spaces from **Column2** as `0`, you can use the following QUERY:

**`=QUERY({A2:A10,ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B10 = "", 0, B2:B10))}, "Select (Col1 + Col2) label (Col1 + Col2) 'SumColumn'")`**

[image]

With the following **`if(B2:B10 = "", 0, B2:B10)`** we make sure that when there's a `BLANK` space, that will be considered as `0` otherwise it will take the number added in the column.

**`"Select (Col1 + Col2) label (Col1 + Col2) 'SumColumn'"`**

I selected sum Column1 and Column2 and I added a label called **SumColumn** showing the result.

In case you would like to export all columns with the labels, you can use the following formula:
**`=QUERY({A2:B10,ARRAYFORMULA(if(B2:B10 = "", 0, B2:B10))}, "Select Col1, Col2, (Col1 + Col3) label Col1 'Column 1', Col2 'Column 2', (Col1 + Col3) 'SumColumn'")`**

[image]

#### **References:**

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en&sjid=1628469046843327306-NA)

Answer (score 0):

Use `BYROW()` function.

```
=BYROW(A2:B8,LAMBDA(rw,SUM(rw)))
```

[image]